# jQuery Sortable with css scaleY

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scale, jquery-ui-sortable

How correctly to change position of `LI` if general `UL` upend by scaleY (css)?

example of problem at here http://jsfiddle.net/ZnQHe/2/ (try to move a list element)

I need `scale(-1)`

[image]

Comment: Why do you have scaleY to -1 ? I changed it to a 1 and the moving of the boxes seemed fine to me.

Comment: I need to list created from the bottom to up (`scale(-1)`). But your variant create list from the up to bottom (`scale(1)`).

Comment: Understood. I have not had time to try this out but can you look at using helper: clone option when initializing your sortable? You could write your own function which actually returns a clone, but sets the transform and scaleY CSS properties as well. This helper is what is shown for dragging.